# What happens to existing threads in Wildfly when we redeploy an application

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, wildfly, java-threads

My application receives data from multiple devices. At any given point in time, there will be more than 1 thread in busy thread count. My question is that, when I redeploy my application which receives data from devices, what happens to the previously running threads.  Will they be blocked? When I checked its count just before uploading new war file, it found to be the same as before undeployment.

So if they are being blocked, what is the best way to deal with this issue?

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using and how are the threads created?

Comment: wildfly 18.0.1.Final

Comment: Each data packets sending to the server has some processing time which is less than 10 ms. Since there many devices, threads are being created.

Comment: So you're asking what happens to incoming requests?

Comment: no, what happens to existing threads

Answer (score 0):

I did some experiment in this area, I proceed as follow

1. Deploy an app
2. Called a rest service, and in the rest service put a `Thread.sleep(20000)` (20 seconds) before the return of the service.
3. Rebuild the app and try to deploy it in during the 20 seconds of sleep of the thread.

The result of the experiment was:

- The server waits until the thread finishes or the time of grace of the Wildfly transaction reaper kills the transaction